# Fatal Exception: java.lang.LinkageError No superclass defined for class com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.signals.n

Tags: android, admob, classnotfoundexception, android-8.1-oreo, linkageerror

This log of Crashlytics error only apears on Android device 
 **Redmi Note 5 Pro** with **OS 8.1.0 (Oreo)**. Getting error frequently on this device only.

I have already added the below line to the Manifest to solved the similar error in live app version:

```
<uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
```

This link says team is working to resolve the same issue:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=Es-419#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/K1HKru7RutY

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.LinkageError
No superclass defined for class com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.signals.n (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.signals.n' appears in /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000007/AdsDynamite.apk)
dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative (DexFile.java)
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:123)
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineKeyFactory.loadClass (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):3)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.load.o.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):7)
aod.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):9)
com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.load.m.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):16)
aod.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):9)
com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.load.n.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):15)
aod.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):9)
com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.interstitial.w.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):9)
aod.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):9)
com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.interstitial.u.a (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799051@14.7.99 (040408-223214910):2)
com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd (Unknown Source:6)
com.myapp.V2.ad.AdSetup.loadInterstatial (AdSetup.java:111)
```

It can be inferred from log that error is happening while trying to load the Interstitial-Ad. How to get rid of this.

Comment: Same issue is happening to me on (**Redmi Note 5**, **Android 8.1.0**), when calling `loadAd()` on an AdMob `InterstitialAd` or `RewardedVideoAd`. Ever since I set API 28 as the app's target SDK version, almost half of all crashes have been from AdMob... 

Comment: @Josselin I have not yet found any solution for this